# The target-entity Collegelife\CommonBundle\Entity\countrycity cannot be found in 'Collegelife\CommonBundle\Entity\Country#countrycityassociation'

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, entity

Thanks to you for refer
I am strucking from a day about an issue that my previous operating system has been changes from windows 7 to ubuntu 12.04.
In my windows, symfony application ran on php 5.5.6 with same in ubuntu application run in 5.5.6 version.But now I got and errors in entity relation. I have tried to resolve it but I am not succeed.

The same code also runs on another windows 7 system but I required to run in linux.

Kindly provide me solution for that.

**Below link is of dropbox where you may found all entities.**

Visit https://www.dropbox.com/sh/rr7d31ah71sagwp/AACb7LW3r0R8ugvaDmkvERACa?dl=0

***Below is Error :***

> Exception detected!
>    The target-entity Collegelife\CommonBundle\Entity\countrycity cannot be found in 'Collegelife\CommonBundle\Entity\Country#countrycityassociation'.

**Stack Trace**

```
in /opt/lampp/htdocs/collegelife/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/MappingException.php at line 740  -
         */
        public static function invalidTargetEntityClass($targetEntity, $sourceEntity, $associationName)
        {
            return new self("The target-entity " . $targetEntity . " cannot be found in '" . $sourceEntity."#".$associationName."'.");
        }
        /**
at MappingException ::invalidTargetEntityClass ('Collegelife\CommonBundle\Entity\countrycity', 'Collegelife\CommonBundle\Entity\Country', 'countrycityassociation')
in /opt/lampp/htdocs/collegelife/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/ClassMetadataInfo.php at line 953  -
        {
            foreach ($this->associationMappings as $mapping) {
                if ( ! ClassLoader::classExists($mapping['targetEntity']) ) {
                    throw MappingException::invalidTargetEntityClass($mapping['targetEntity'], $this->name, $mapping['fieldName']);
                }
            }
        }
at ClassMetadataInfo ->validateAssociations ()
in /opt/lampp/htdocs/collegelife/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/ClassMetadataFactory.php at line 199  -
            }
            $class->validateIdentifier();
            $class->validateAssociations();
            $class->validateLifecycleCallbacks($this->getReflectionService());
            // verify inheritance
at ClassMetadataFactory ->validateRuntimeMetadata (object(ClassMetadata), null)
in /opt/lampp/htdocs/collegelife/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/ClassMetadataFactory.php at line 178  -
                $this->evm->dispatchEvent(Events::loadClassMetadata, $eventArgs);
            }
            $this->validateRuntimeMetadata($class, $parent);
        }
        /**
at ClassMetadataFactory ->doLoadMetadata (object(ClassMetadata), null, false, array())
in /opt/lampp/htdocs/collegelife/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/Mapping/AbstractClassMetadataFactory.php at line 318  -
                $class = $this->newClassMetadataInstance($className);
                $this->initializeReflection($class, $reflService);
                $this->doLoadMetadata($class, $parent, $rootEntityFound, $visited);
                $this->loadedMetadata[$className] = $class;
at AbstractClassMetadataFactory ->loadMetadata ('Collegelife\CommonBundle\Entity\Country')
in /opt/lampp/htdocs/collegelife/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/Mapping/AbstractClassMetadataFactory.php at line 211  -
                    $this->loadedMetadata[$realClassName] = $cached;
                    $this->wakeupReflection($cached, $this->getReflectionService());
                } else {
                    foreach ($this->loadMetadata($realClassName) as $loadedClassName) {
                        $this->cacheDriver->save(
                            $loadedClassName . $this->cacheSalt, $this->loadedMetadata[$loadedClassName], null
                        );
at AbstractClassMetadataFactory ->getMetadataFor ('CollegelifeCommonBundle:Country')
in /opt/lampp/htdocs/collegelife/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/EntityManager.php at line 295  -
         */
        public function getClassMetadata($className)
        {
            return $this->metadataFactory->getMetadataFor($className);
        }
        /**
at EntityManager ->getClassMetadata ('CollegelifeCommonBundle:Country')
in /opt/lampp/htdocs/collegelife/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Repository/DefaultRepositoryFactory.php at line 67  -
         */
        protected function createRepository(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager, $entityName)
        {
            $metadata            = $entityManager->getClassMetadata($entityName);
            $repositoryClassName = $metadata->customRepositoryClassName;
            if ($repositoryClassName === null) {
at DefaultRepositoryFactory ->createRepository (object(EntityManager), 'CollegelifeCommonBundle:Country')
in /opt/lampp/htdocs/collegelife/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Repository/DefaultRepositoryFactory.php at line 50  -
                return $this->repositoryList[$entityName];
            }
            $repository = $this->createRepository($entityManager, $entityName);
            $this->repositoryList[$entityName] = $repository;
at DefaultRepositoryFactory ->getRepository (object(EntityManager), 'CollegelifeCommonBundle:Country')
in /opt/lampp/htdocs/collegelife/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/EntityManager.php at line 759  -
         */
        public function getRepository($entityName)
        {
            return $this->repositoryFactory->getRepository($this, $entityName);
        }
        /**
at EntityManager ->getRepository ('CollegelifeCommonBundle:Country')
in /opt/lampp/htdocs/collegelife/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/AbstractManagerRegistry.php at line 239  -
         */
        public function getRepository($persistentObjectName, $persistentManagerName = null)
        {
            return $this->getManager($persistentManagerName)->getRepository($persistentObjectName);
        }
        /**
at AbstractManagerRegistry ->getRepository ('CollegelifeCommonBundle:Country')
in /opt/lampp/htdocs/collegelife/src/Collegelife/AdminBundle/Controller/CountryController.php at line 123  -
            if (false === $this->get("security.context")->isGranted("ROLE_ADMIN")) {
                throw new AccessDeniedException("Unable access this page");
            }
            $entity = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository("CollegelifeCommonBundle:Country")->findAll();
            return $this->render("CollegelifeAdminBundle:Country:list.html.twig", array("entity" => $entity));
        }
at CountryController ->listAction (object(Request))
at call_user_func_array (array(object(CountryController), 'listAction'), array(object(Request)))
in kernel.root_dir/bootstrap.php.cache at line 2889  -
    $this->dispatcher->dispatch(KernelEvents::CONTROLLER, $event);
    $controller = $event->getController();
    $arguments = $this->resolver->getArguments($request, $controller);
    $response = call_user_func_array($controller, $arguments);
    if (!$response instanceof Response) {
    $event = new GetResponseForControllerResultEvent($this, $request, $type, $response);
    $this->dispatcher->dispatch(KernelEvents::VIEW, $event);
at HttpKernel ->handleRaw (object(Request), '1')
in kernel.root_dir/bootstrap.php.cache at line 2863  -
    public function handle(Request $request, $type = HttpKernelInterface::MASTER_REQUEST, $catch = true)
    {
    try {
    return $this->handleRaw($request, $type);
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
    if (false === $catch) {
    throw $e;
at HttpKernel ->handle (object(Request), '1', true)
in kernel.root_dir/bootstrap.php.cache at line 2992  -
    $this->container->enterScope('request');
    $this->container->set('request', $request,'request');
    try {
    $response = parent::handle($request, $type, $catch);
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
    $this->container->set('request', null,'request');
    $this->container->leaveScope('request');
at ContainerAwareHttpKernel ->handle (object(Request), '1', true)
in kernel.root_dir/bootstrap.php.cache at line 2272  -
    if (false === $this->booted) {
    $this->boot();
    }
    return $this->getHttpKernel()->handle($request, $type, $catch);
    }
    protected function getHttpKernel()
    {
at Kernel ->handle (object(Request))
in /opt/lampp/htdocs/collegelife/web/app_dev.php at line 28  -
    $kernel = new AppKernel('dev', true);
    $kernel->loadClassCache();
    $request = Request::createFromGlobals();
    $response = $kernel->handle($request);
    $response->send();
    $kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

**Log**

```
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ProfilerListener::onKernelRequest".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\EventListener\SessionListener::onKernelRequest".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\FragmentListener::onKernelRequest".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\RouterListener::onKernelRequest".
INFO - Matched route "_admin_country_list" (parameters: "_controller": "Collegelife\AdminBundle\Controller\CountryController::listAction", "_route": "_admin_country_list")
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\LocaleListener::onKernelRequest".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall::onKernelRequest".
DEBUG - Read SecurityContext from the session
DEBUG - Reloading user from user provider.
DEBUG - SELECT t0.id AS id1, t0.firstname AS firstname2, t0.lastname AS lastname3, t0.email AS email4, t0.password AS password5, t0.created_at AS created_at6, t0.updated_at AS updated_at7 FROM admin t0 WHERE t0.email = ? LIMIT 1
DEBUG - Username "admin@collegelife.com" was reloaded from user provider.
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\AsseticBundle\EventListener\RequestListener::onKernelRequest".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ErrorsLoggerListener::injectLogger".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ErrorsLoggerListener::injectLogger".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\DataCollector\RouterDataCollector::onKernelController".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DataCollector\RequestDataCollector::onKernelController".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\ControllerListener::onKernelController".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\ParamConverterListener::onKernelController".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\TemplateListener::onKernelController".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.exception" to listener "Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall\ExceptionListener::onKernelException".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.exception" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ProfilerListener::onKernelException".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.exception" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ExceptionListener::onKernelException".
CRITICAL - Uncaught PHP Exception Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\MappingException: "The target-entity Collegelife\CommonBundle\Entity\countrycity cannot be found in 'Collegelife\CommonBundle\Entity\Country#countrycityassociation'." at /opt/lampp/htdocs/collegelife/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/MappingException.php line 740
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ProfilerListener::onKernelRequest".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\EventListener\SessionListener::onKernelRequest".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\FragmentListener::onKernelRequest".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\RouterListener::onKernelRequest".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\LocaleListener::onKernelRequest".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall::onKernelRequest".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\AsseticBundle\EventListener\RequestListener::onKernelRequest".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ErrorsLoggerListener::injectLogger".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ErrorsLoggerListener::injectLogger".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\DataCollector\RouterDataCollector::onKernelController".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DataCollector\RequestDataCollector::onKernelController".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\ControllerListener::onKernelController".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\ParamConverterListener::onKernelController".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\TemplateListener::onKernelController".
```

**Stack Trace(Plain Text)**

[1] Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\MappingException: The target-entity Collegelife\CommonBundle\Entity\countrycity cannot be found in 'Collegelife\CommonBundle\Entity\Country#countrycityassociation'.
    at n/a
        in /opt/lampp/htdocs/collegelife/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/MappingException.php line 740

```
at Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\MappingException::invalidTargetEntityClass('Collegelife\CommonBundle\Entity\countrycity', 'Collegelife\CommonBundle\Entity\Country', 'countrycityassociation')
    in /opt/lampp/htdocs/collegelife/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/ClassMetadataInfo.php line 953

at Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadataInfo->validateAssociations()
    in /opt/lampp/htdocs/collegelife/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/ClassMetadataFactory.php line 199

at Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadataFactory->validateRuntimeMetadata(object(ClassMetadata), null)
    in /opt/lampp/htdocs/collegelife/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/ClassMetadataFactory.php line 178

at Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadataFactory->doLoadMetadata(object(ClassMetadata), null, false, array())
    in /opt/lampp/htdocs/collegelife/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/Mapping/AbstractClassMetadataFactory.php line 318

at Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\AbstractClassMetadataFactory->loadMetadata('Collegelife\CommonBundle\Entity\Country')
    in /opt/lampp/htdocs/collegelife/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/Mapping/AbstractClassMetadataFactory.php line 211

at Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\AbstractClassMetadataFactory->getMetadataFor('CollegelifeCommonBundle:Country')
    in /opt/lampp/htdocs/collegelife/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/EntityManager.php line 295

at Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager->getClassMetadata('CollegelifeCommonBundle:Country')
    in /opt/lampp/htdocs/collegelife/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Repository/DefaultRepositoryFactory.php line 67

at Doctrine\ORM\Repository\DefaultRepositoryFactory->createRepository(object(EntityManager), 'CollegelifeCommonBundle:Country')
    in /opt/lampp/htdocs/collegelife/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Repository/DefaultRepositoryFactory.php line 50

at Doctrine\ORM\Repository\DefaultRepositoryFactory->getRepository(object(EntityManager), 'CollegelifeCommonBundle:Country')
    in /opt/lampp/htdocs/collegelife/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/EntityManager.php line 759

at Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager->getRepository('CollegelifeCommonBundle:Country')
    in /opt/lampp/htdocs/collegelife/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/AbstractManagerRegistry.php line 239

at Doctrine\Common\Persistence\AbstractManagerRegistry->getRepository('CollegelifeCommonBundle:Country')
    in /opt/lampp/htdocs/collegelife/src/Collegelife/AdminBundle/Controller/CountryController.php line 123

at Collegelife\AdminBundle\Controller\CountryController->listAction(object(Request))
    in  line 

at call_user_func_array(array(object(CountryController), 'listAction'), array(object(Request)))
    in /opt/lampp/htdocs/collegelife/app/bootstrap.php.cache line 2889

at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleRaw(object(Request), '1')
    in /opt/lampp/htdocs/collegelife/app/bootstrap.php.cache line 2863

at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle(object(Request), '1', true)
    in /opt/lampp/htdocs/collegelife/app/bootstrap.php.cache line 2992

at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DependencyInjection\ContainerAwareHttpKernel->handle(object(Request), '1', true)
    in /opt/lampp/htdocs/collegelife/app/bootstrap.php.cache line 2272

at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->handle(object(Request))
    in /opt/lampp/htdocs/collegelife/web/app_dev.php line 28
```

Comment: Filesystems on linux boxes are case sensitive.  Windows is not.  "Entity\countrycity"  I'm betting your class is actually CountryCity.  You need to go through and make sure all file names match class names exactly.

Comment: Cerad I have updated all files in dropbox where I had changes required.

Comment: Not sure what that means but okay.  Drop the log and stack trace from your question.  Add the mapping between Country and CountryCity.  You are using countrycity somewhere when it should be CountryCity.

Comment: Resolved. Thanks to all.